# How to do correlation in HTTP Header manager which producing dynamic values

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, correlation

[image]

In the above picture we are facing the dynamic values in content type,so we are try to correlation for that but it is unable to read the dynamic value from the server.
[image]

Please check the correlation value which we done, Please help us on this issue.

Comment: why you have 'f' letter before (.*)?

Comment: search for response or request headers?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong 'f' was removed now, but still we are getting the same error.

Comment: wha'ts the error? it seems also you are sending type variable and trying to find it in header and set it back to variable? why do you need that?

Comment: @user7294900 the dynamic values from HTTP Header manager

Comment: @user7294900 Actually we are find the dynamic value from HTTP Header manager So we are try to capture that but unable to capture that value.

Comment: Are you trying to get the ${type} value from a previous response and use it in the header manager in the next HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Header Manager is defining **additional request** headers which **you** are sending with the request.

I don't really understand why you are trying to extract the value from the request header which you define **yourself**.

If you are trying to perform a [file upload](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) or your application expects [multipart/form-data](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) content type you can send this header automatically ticking the relevant checkbox in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image: HTTP Request multipart data]

---

In general I would recommend recording your test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it should be smart enough to generate the relevant test plan skeleton.